# Bug in complicated Limit

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs

The code

```
Limit[Log[2 - Sin[x]*Cos[x]], x -> Infinity]
```

outputs

```
Interval[{0, Log[3]}]
```

in Mathematica 10.0.2.0 . It should be

```
Interval[{Log[3/2]}, Log[5/2]}]
```

instead of. Is there a workaround?

Comment: If you are looking to report a bug, please contact Wolfram support directly.  What sort of workaround are you looking for?

Comment: Regarding your last edit: Please do not include the bugs tag when you post a new question.  It will be added after the community confirms it as an actual bug.  http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/354/12

Comment: @ Szabolcs: Thank you. I have not known about Wolfram support. Maybe, some modification of the code gives the right answer. BTW, I inserted the bug tag, but forum changed to bugs.

Comment: @user64494 This is not an official Wolfram site.  We are just users like you.  It's better to report bugs to Wolfram, to make sure they have the chance to fix it.  That will benefit everyone.

Comment: @ Szabolcs: I see about 5 hundred questions tagged bugs in the forum.

Comment: Posting here as in addition reporting the bug to support is also a very nice option in my opinion.

Comment: @user64494 Most or all of those 500 questions were vetted by the community first before they received the bugs tag. The tag description (mouseover the tag) mentions that as well. Anyway, `Limit[Sin[x]*Cos[x], x -> Infinity]` is a simple example of the bug.

Comment: @user64494 The idea is that the tag should not be added by the person who posts the question.  When appropriate, it will be added by others.  Please read the link I posted.  While here the situation is pretty clear, the majority of bug claims on this site turn out not to be bugs.

Comment: `Limit` does not in general find the tightest possible interval for functions that oscillate.

Comment: (Apropos of tagging,) I do not regard this as a bug.

Comment: Fixed in 13.3.1 or earlier. `Limit[Log[2 - Sin[x]*Cos[x]], x -> Infinity]` outputs `Indeterminate` and `MinLimit[Log[2 - Sin[x]*Cos[x]], x -> Infinity] // FullSimplify` results in `Log[3/2]` and `MaxLimit[Log[2 - Sin[x]*Cos[x]], x -> Infinity] // FullSimplify` performs `Log[5/2]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Slow down the approach,

```
Limit[Log[2 - Sin[x]*Cos[x]] /. x -> x/2, x -> Infinity]
```

or speed it up,

```
Limit[Log[2 - Sin[x]*Cos[x]] /. x -> 2 x, x -> Infinity]
```

-- both yield

```
Interval[{Log[3/2], Log[5/2]}]
```

Comment: Any idea why this works?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I had an idea when I tried it, but not after looking at the `Trace`, which was unilluminating. My feeling was that the transformation `Sin[2x] -> 2 Sin[x] Cos[x]`, getting the trig. fns. in terms of `x` (e.g. `TrigExpand`), and `Sin`, `Cos` being between `±1` might be tempting *M*. Changing `x` in the above and similar ways seems to work, perhaps by preventing the double angle formula from being applied. It was basically a guess. BTW, in my view of how `Limit` and `Interval` work, I think both results are "correct," although a more precise result is more desirable.

Answer (score 5):

A limited kind of work-around:

```
expr = Log[2 - Sin[x]*Cos[x]];

TrigReduce //@ expr /. x -> Interval[∞]
```

> ```
> Interval[{Log[3/2], Log[5/2]}]
> ```

Comment: Sorry, I don't see any Limit in your code. You found the range of expr = Log[2 - Sin[x]*Cos[x]];.

Comment: @user64494 Yes, it is not very general.  The result is right in the particular case however, is it not?

Comment: @ Mr.Wizard: Could that be called a workaround? I think the answer is no.

Comment: @user64494 Hey, I'm trying. :^)

Comment: @user64494 Why do you say Mr.Wizard found the range? Other than the fact that your so-called limit is the same as the range, which is itself a source of confusion in any case, the computation does not represent finding the range.  It more closely represents finding the limit.

Answer (score 4):

```
f[x_] = Log[2 - Sin[x]*Cos[x]];

Simplify[f[x] == f[x + n Pi], Element[n, Integers]]
```

> True

Since the function is periodic, the limit interval is just the minimum and maximum of the function.

```
Interval@(f[x] /. Solve[{f'[x] == 0, 0 <= x <= 2 Pi}, x, Reals] // 
    FullSimplify // Union)
```

> Interval[{Log[3/2], Log[5/2]}]

Alternatively, with version 10

```
FunctionRange[f[x], x, y] // FullSimplify
```

> Log[3/2] <= y <= Log[5/2]

```
Interval@Cases[%, _?NumericQ]
```

> Interval[{Log[3/2], Log[5/2]}]

Comment: @ Bob Hanlon : Having  noticed "Since the function is periodic, the limit interval is just the minimum and maximum of the function",   you found the minimum and the maximum. This is true only for continuous functions. Nevertheless, I find it smart. However, that way is found by hand and only realized with Mathematica. Could that be called a workaround?

Comment: @ Bob Hanlon: One of the votes up is mine.